# Compare columns from two tables using regular expression and search criteria

Tags: oracle, regexp-substr

I require to compare table.column1 with table.column2 by using regular expression but I also want to introduce addition search criteria like following.

```
regexp_substr(table.column1,'[[:space:]] table.column2 [ $]')
```

But the challenge I don't find a way to include actual column2 withing the search criteria.

I think it is related to syntax error. I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks,
shahid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may concatenate the contents of column2 to the expression.

```
regexp_substr(t.column1,'[[:space:]] '||t.column2||' [ $]')
```

Comment: Thanks Kaushik, I had just done that and it worked. Thanks for the answer.